# How to callback one JavaScript function into multiple functions?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have some JavaScript function like below:-

```js
function temp() {
    var rep ="some";
}



function solve() {
  function temp();
  $("#demo").text('solve1:'+rep);
}

function solve1() {
  function temp();
  $("#demo1").text('solve2:'+rep);
}
  
function solve2() {
  function temp();
  $("#demo2").text('solve3:'+rep);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<button onclick="solve()">solve</button><br>
<button onclick="solve1()">solve</button><br>
<button onclick="solve2()">solve</button><br>
```

My question is how to callback first `function temp()` into all other three functions. Above script is not working. How do I include one JavaScript function within multiple functions?

Comment: scope of variable `rep` is inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to return the value of the variable `rep` from your `temp()` function. Then wherever you call that function the value will be available. Note that you don't have to use the keyword `function` while calling the function. Just the name of the function will do. See the code comments to understand better.

```js
function temp() {
    var rep = "some";
    return rep;        // Return the value of the 'rep' variable.
}



function solve() {
  var rep = temp();        // Call the 'temp()' function defined above.
  $("#demo").text('solve1:'+rep);
}

function solve1() {
  var rep = temp();
  $("#demo1").text('solve2:'+rep);
}
  
function solve2() {
  var rep = temp();
  $("#demo2").text('solve3:'+rep);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<button onclick="solve()">solve</button><br>
<button onclick="solve1()">solve</button><br>
<button onclick="solve2()">solve</button><br>
```